# How can I set the default font size for all Qt5 apps?

Tags: configuration, fonts, qt

I run Gnome, which has pretty good support for my HiDPI screen. However, when I run QT apps I can't seem to find a way to scale the fonts. Is there a way to do this without installing a full version of KDE?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Updated:

Since Qt 5.6, Qt 5 applications can be instructed to honor screen DPI by setting the `QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR` environment variable. If automatic detection of DPI does not produce the desired effect, scaling can be set manually per-screen (`QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS`) or globally (`QT_SCALE_FACTOR`). You can also use `QT_FONT_DPI` to adjust scaling of text.

Original:

You can try [this recipe](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI#Qt_5) from the archwiki

> Qt5 applications can often be run at higher dpi by setting the QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO environment variable. Note that the variable has to be set to a whole integer, so setting it to 1.5 will not work.
>
> This can for instance be enabled by creating a file `/etc/profile.d/qt-hidpi.sh`
>
> `export QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO=2`
>
> And set the executable bit on it.

Answer (score 12):

`QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO` is deprecated since 5.4; instead, use `QT_SCALE_FACTOR`. I use it, setting it to 1.5, with good results (e.g., VirtualBox 5.1)

Answer (score 6):

QT [automatically scales the font](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.10/highdpi.html) based on the screen's DPI:

> The traditional approach to supporting high DPI has been one where Qt scaled fonts automatically [...]

I had the problem that my screen has 166 dpi, but the font sizes chosen by Qt were much too large. Luckily, there is a way to tell Qt to assume a smaller value by setting `QT_FONT_DPI`. For me, 128 is nice.

(I'm using cinnamon as desktop environment, and it pushes the configured font sizes for Gtk 1:1 to Qt, which is what brings this issue)

Comment: This works better than any other Qt setting, and you can use it inline when you run an app to tune as needed, eg:  `QT_FONT_DPI=128 bin/robo3t &`

Answer (score 3):

I had the problem, that apps like KeepassXC and VLC have tiny, unreadable fonts now in Linux Mint 20 Ulyana (Cinnamon Edition).
To make my QT-Apps look normal, I needed both solutions mentioned here and put following lines into `/etc/profile.d/qt-fix.sh`:

```bsh
# For the graphical elements
export QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1.5 

# To make the fonts readable
export QT_FONT_DPI=96
```

Although I read, that QT scales automatically, scaling only the fonts lead to strange look with unexpected line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

```
'export QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO=2'
```

is deprecated.

Instead use:

```
export QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=1
```